# I used $location.search to set paramValue, but if i select other link also it get appended to new url, how to solve it

Tags: angularjs, search, location

In Angularjs I used $location.search() to set paramValue in url i.e like

if i change dropdown executeSearch() will be called.

```
executeSearch() 
{
  $location.search('type', Task);
}

result is : index.html#/search?type=Task.
```

but if i click on other link also it coming like

```
index.html#/help?type=Task
```

how to make it specific to this function only..if i click on other link also **?type=Task** get appended. so how to remove this paramvalues("**? folled by paramvalues**") if i click on other links.

```
<select class="search-dropdown-select" ng-change="SearchBar.executeSearch()"
                        ng-model="SearchBar[item.model]"
                        ng-options="item.name for item in SearchBar.{{item.options}}"></select>
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML too?

Comment: And why do you use $location.search? May be `executeSearch` shoud execute a service/factory instead changing the current URL.

Comment: Thanks for ur response...Actually location.search() it is in one module, but it is affecting in another module also...i mean if i click other element link it get appended to it. so how to resolve this.

Comment: That's how AngularJS works. You are wrong if you wanna use something like that in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on the other link use `$location.url()`.  This will clear all of the query parameters.

```
function navigate(path) {
  $location.url(path);
}
```

`<a href ng-click="navigate('/help')">Help</a>`